# Apache does not update documentation? Major Bug in Java

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm getting this error

> Cannot display ObjectMessage body. Reason: Failed to build the body from content. Serializable class not available to the broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class com.company.data.TicketData! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at [this](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html) for more information on how to configure trusted classes.

I added `System.setProperty("org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES","*");` in my code that invokes the creation of the JMS and doesn't work.

I also set `setx org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES "*"` in the cmd but still the same error.

Even if you check the error [page](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html).

it talks about an env script file that does not exist when you download the Apache ActiveMQ.

What can I do?? There are some files in /config but I don't see how do enable this? Why Apache has documentation that even doesn't work?

Comment: where are you setting the property, client or broker ?

Comment: The title for this question is ambiguous.  Please reword to clarify what the actual issue is (i.e. something related to de/serialization of object messages).

Comment: Correction grammar and formatted.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. The Java runtime of your broker can only deserialize the ObjectMessage if

1. The class is part of the broker's classpath. The exception
   "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" sounds like that's the issue. Try adding your company's jar file into the ActiveMQ classpath.
2. The class implements java.io.Serializable. Adding something to your
   client's Java runtime won't help. It must be know to the broker, so
   best is really to let your class implement that interface.
3. ActiveMQ
   also requires to 'trust' an Object. So your **Broker** must have this class whitelisted, for example by starting the Broker with -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=* - this only works onwards from a certain ActiveMQ version > 5.12.2

Quite frankly, you should stay away from JMS ObjectMessage. There was an ActiveMQ bug in the area a while ago and it's a constant security hole. Try to send as BytesMessage as externalized Object, or maybe send your Object as TextMessage in XML or JSON format.